# Proxy website that uses javascript to change window.location?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, javascript

Little bit of a newb when it comes to configuring httpd but here's my situation:

I'm trying to proxy an application (let's call it *catsapp*) that I have no control over with httpd.

*catsapp*, an html/javascript application, has httpd running in front of it as well. But I can't mess with that configuration, I can only control the top-level httpd config.

Turns out that inside of the `index.html` of *catsapp*, there is a javascript call:

```
window.location="viewer.html"
```

Which is meant to load the viewer page.

Normally, writing the `ProxyPass` directive is easy enough and this is what I have currently:

```
ProxyPass /catsapp http://catsapp-server timeout=600
ProxyPassReverse /catsapp http://catsapp-server timeout=600
```

This does not work however. If I navigate to `example.com/catsapp` I get a `200 OK` followed immediately by `404 Not Found` because the browser tries to load `example.com/viewer.html` instead of `example.com/catsapp/viewer.html`.

Is there some way to configure the root httpd server so that when *catsapp* calls `window.location="viewer.html"` it resolves to `example.com/catsapp/viewer.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that there are multiple resources that need to be loaded from your application, so `example.com/catsapp` should look a subdirectory. Without a trailing slash, browsers see `example.com/catsapp` as a file-like resource, not a folder-like resource. Following the link `viewer.html` relative to `example.com/catsapp` leads to `example.com/viewer.html`. However, resolving `viewer.html` relative to `example.com/catsapp/` (notice the trailing slash) resolves to `example.com/catsapp/viewer.html`.

I would suggest redirecting `example.com/catsapp` to `example.com/catsapp/` (not internally but via HTTP 3xx) and editing your `ProxyPass` rule to also include the trailing slash. For example:

```
Redirect permanent /catsapp /catsapp/
ProxyPass /catsapp/ http://catsapp-server/ timeout=600
ProxyPassReverse /catsapp/ http://catsapp-server/ timeout=600
```

Comment: Interesting. If I remove my rewrite rule and alter my Proxy/ProxyPass to: `ProxyPass /catsapp http://catsapp/ timeout=600` and `ProxyPassReverse /catsapp http://catsapp/ timeout=600`; when I request `http://example.com/catsapp` it still incorrectly resolves to `http://example.com/viewer.html` **but** if I request `http://example.com/catsapp/` is does redirect correctly to `http://example.com/catsapp/viewer.html`

Comment: Keep in mind that it mind that it's the browser who does the relative resolving. The browser is instructed to go to `viewer.html`, so it resolves that relative to what it sees as the current address. Therefor, you must make sure that the browser never gets to `example.com/catsapp`, but only to `example.com/catsapp/`.

Comment: I just noticed my description may be misleading. You mustn't redirect the request to `example.com/catsapp` *internally* to `example.com/catsapp/`, but instruct the browser via HTTP 3xx to go visit that address instead. If the browser however requests the page with the slash (or any subresource), ProxyPass the request to the application server.

Comment: Aha! That makes much more sense now. I've implemented rules as you suggest and everything works. I've edited my working configuration into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging it looks like what I want to do is not "easily" possible. I now understand that the problem is this:

1. Browser requests example.com/catsapp
2. Root httpd server intercepts request and forwards to http://catsapp-server/
3. catsapp-server httpd receives requests and returns index.html
4. Root httpd server returns response to client
5. Browser receives index.html
6. Browser changes location to example.com/viewer.html (because the javascript told it to)

So the erroneous URL is being decided client-side after httpd is out of the picture. What it seems I would have to do is use something like `mod_substitute` to alter the response being sent back to the client in step #4 to insert my custom `/catsapp` path before `viewer.html`. Sounds ugly and prone to error.

---

What I decided to do instead seems to be a little more robust but still pretty specific to this use case. I noticed that `index.html` exists only to redirect the client to `viewer.html`. So why don't I just do that automatically during step #2 above? I tried that by adding a `RewriteRule` to the root httpd server.

```
RewriteRule (.*/catsapp) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/viewer.html [R,L]
```

And it seems to be working just fine. I don't *think* there are other areas of the application that try changing location like `index.html` does and this solution wouldn't work for any cases where that happens... so here's hoping it works out.

Comment: Even though I settled on a workaround, I want to leave this question open in case I'm wrong or missing something. Please comment or add an answer if you disagree with my analysis/approach.